# grouping elements dynamically inside arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to javascript. I have a list of 500 or more items. I need split this array into sub arrays each containing 20 items. i.e 25 arrays if there are exactly 500 items and each array containing 20 items. I created 25 arrays like below:

```
var firstSet=[];
var secondSet=[];
.....
```

And i populate each of this array using the for loop. In javascript how can I make it programmatically since the main list can return more than 500 items in future and each sub array should be configured for more than 20 items in future. What is the best solution to fix this situation?

Comment: You should use a 2-dimensional array, not lots of separate variables.

Comment: Can you please show me an example?

Comment: Are you looking for the js equivalent to the PHP `array_chunk`? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments say, you should split it with a 2 dimentional array:

```
var mainArray=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function splitArray(arr,qty){
    var mainArr=[], subarr=[];
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        subarr.push(arr[i]);
        if( ((i+1) % qty == 0) || i+1==arr.length){
            mainArr.push(subarr);
            subarr=[];
        }
    }
    return mainArr;
}

console.log(splitArray(mainArray,2));
```

This creates 1 array with 5 indexes. In each index, you have an array of 2 elements. So it groups it in [1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [9,10]

Answer (score -1):

Use nested loops to create a 2-dimensional array from the original data.

```
var sets = [];
var items_per_set = 20;
for (var i = 0, outer = 0; i < list.length; i += items_per_set, outer++) {
    sets[outer] = [];
    var limit = Math.min(list.length, i+items_per_set);
    for (j = i; j < limit; j++) {
        sets[outer].push(list[j]);
    }
}
```